# discrete vs. continuous random variable: a specific example

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Here is my example: 
A person talks on the phone. A define a random variable as a number of minutes his/her conversation will continue. Suppose, such conversation can continue to infinity. Will this variable qualify to be defined as a continuous variable? Note, that I defined the values in minutes, so if for example duration of the conversation was limited by some external factor, then it would have been a discreet variable for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: A discrete random variable can take infinitely many values (see the Poisson/Geometric distribution). What's important is whether we are measuring minutes over the non-negative integers or real numbers.

Comment: But how it then corresponds with the definition that "A discrete random variable has a countable number of possible values"  https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-statistics/chapter/discrete-random-variables/

Comment: It says countable, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set: "a countable set is a set with the same cardinality (number of elements) as some subset of the set of natural numbers. A countable set is either a finite set or a countably infinite set. Whether finite or infinite, the elements of a countable set can always be counted one at a time and, although the counting may never finish, every element of the set is associated with a unique natural number."

Comment: I see, thanks  a lot